# A comment may not be placed within the bracketed statement

Tags: c#, coding-style, stylecop

I am using StyleCop on my C# files and it gives the warning :

> SA1108 : CSharp.Readability : A comment may not be placed within the bracketed statement

for the following block of code :

```
// checking if the person is born or not.
if (AgeUtilities.IsPersonBorn(person.BirthDate) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error....The user is not yet born.");
}

// checking if the person's age is possible or not.
else if (AgeUtilities.IsPersonLongAgePossible(age, EXPECTEDAGELIMIT) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This age is not possible in Today's world.");
}
```

What is the significance of this warning?

Comment: I don't use StyleCop but it looks to me as though since you are adding empty space between your `if/elseif` then you are opening yourself up to potential errors as other developers may not notice the `else if` as this code is expanded upon and include another `if` statement, thus buggering up your program. Personally I think since you have given pretty self explanatory method names, you don't need comments here

Comment: @Sayse Even after removing the empty line, the same warning comes.

Comment: In this case, you should treat the comment as an empty line as well. My point is that it is easy to see that the `elseif` belongs with the `if` statement if you can see the bracket above it (or the if statement two lines above it if no brackets)

Comment: Do not use unnecessary comments in your code, such as in this case: the code itself is perfectly understandable. The comments are redundant and just introduce noise which makes the code less readable. Also, whenever you or someone else changes something in this piece of code you will have to change the comments as well (and someone WILL forget to do so and make the code/comments incoherent).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

StyleCop tells you that you should replace/reorganise your comment above the else-statement inside the brackets, like

```
    // checking if the person is born or not
    // if not: check if the person's age is possible or not
    if (AgeUtilities.IsPersonBorn(person.BirthDate) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error....The user is not yet born.");
    }
    else if (AgeUtilities.IsPersonLongAgePossible(age, EXPECTEDAGELIMIT) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This age is not possible in Today's world.");
    }
```

Have a look [here](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1108.html) and [there](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/214841).

Comment: If there are multiple "else if" statements having complex conditions, then is commenting like this the best approach?

Comment: sure it's not - what i prefer to do when i am facing multiple else-if-statements is, that i am extracting the statement itself (like AgeUtilities.isPersonBorn(person.BirthDate) == false) and put it into a function that returns me a boolean and call it PersonIsBorn(), for example.
this approach leads to less comments and better readability - and it will get easier to test the code, as you can "simply" access the methods and its return values via a mock/stub.